# Rowcolor not working when tabular contents is in a separated file

Tags: tables, input, rowcolor

I am having some issues in using `rowcolor` in some tables that have the contents in separated files. The following code works normally

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c}
A & B & C\\
\toprule
\rowcolor{mygray} \textbf{X}    & 1 & 2\\
\textbf{Y}                      & 3 & 4\\
\rowcolor{mygray} \textbf{Z}    & 5 & 6\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

but as soon as I put the contents of the table in a separated file I get the following error:

> Misplaced \noalign.\rowcolor ->\noalign{\ifnum 0=`}\fi \global \let \CT@do@color \CT@@do@color... \rowcolor

The files are

```
%% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c}
A & B & C\\
\toprule

\input{tab}

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

and

```
%% tab.tex
\rowcolor{mygray} \textbf{X}    & 1 & 2\\
\textbf{Y}                      & 3 & 4\\
\rowcolor{mygray} \textbf{Z}    & 5 & 6\\
```

Comment: \rowcoor needs to be the first thing after expansion and \input isn't expandable in latex, ypu can use `\@@input tab` if you use `\makeatletter before the tabular

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, it worked as a charm! Can you elaborate more inside an answer with more details, when and if you have time?

Comment: it's probably a duplicate, I'll look later (next release we'll probaly add a no @ version of this so you can use it more easily)

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have directly the expected result (provided you don't put the last `\\` in the file `tab.tex`, otherwise, you have one more row in the tabular).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{l|c|c}[colortbl-like]
A & B & C\\
\toprule
\input{tab}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And `tab.tex`:

```
%% tab.tex
\rowcolor{mygray}\textbf{X}    & 1 & 2\\
\textbf{Y}                     & 3 & 4\\
\rowcolor{mygray}\textbf{Z}    & 5 & 6
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Replace  `\usepackage{color, colortbl}` with `\usepackage[table]{xtabular}` package  and for coloring of table rows use command `rowcolors{1}{white}{mygray}` inserted before `tabular`:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[varwidth, border=3.141592]{standalone}

\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.9}


\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{white}{mygray}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l|c|c}
\normalfont{A}  & B & C \\
    \midrule
\input{tab}
   \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Result is not very nice (due to use of the rules from `booktabs` which are not intended for use with vertical rules, you may replace it with `\hline`, see image below), but it seems that you like to have above result;-)

[image]

*Remark*:
Inserting table contents on your way is not smart idea. Better is to compose complete table with use of the `standalone` document class, which you can test independent from main document, and then insert complete file in document, which need to have in preamble `usepackage{standalone}`.